# How to get logs from the ipa installed on my iOS device?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Since I am a beginner in iOS development I am in a learning phase so please bear with this question.
I got an ipa from the client to install on my iPhone . However while using the app after installing through .ipa I got an error , can someone tell how can I get the logs from ipa file so that I can understand this error and pass logs to the api team? I know I can get by connecting the device and running/building through xcode directly but unfortunately code is with client and he generates the ipa. Is it possible to get the logs through ipa? I tried to use `View Device Logs` from `Window -> Device and Simulators` by selecting my device but those logs are not which I want

I found several answers like adding the below code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log",[NSDate date]];
NSString *logFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
freopen([logFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"a+",stderr);
```

Is it possible to get logs from **ipa** file as we get from APK file in Android? If yes, can someone tell how to get the logs from `ipa` file?

Comment: Where it is located? But how it will log runtime logs?

Comment: Logs are not part of the .ipa file. If you can connect your device via Xcode, you should be able to go to `Window -> Devices and Simulators -> View Device Logs`. A better approach, though, is to use TestFlight so the crash logs can be automatically accessed by the developer.

Comment: First of all seems you are using some hand-crafted logging there. This _might_ be justified in some cases, but in most cases you should use `os.log` provided by apple. But to answer your question I would need to know: can you plug in your device to a Mac, or do you want to collect logs from some random user's device?